# Parse double on string giving wrong result

Tags: java, parsing, double

In my project I am getting a string values from an api and need to pass double values to another api. When I try to parse from string values to double I am not getting the original data.

Here is the code.

```
String l1="11352721345377306";
String l2="11352721346734307";
String l3="11352721346734308";
String l4="11352721346734309";

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");

System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(l1)));
System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(l2)));
System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(l3)));  
System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(l4)));
```

The output is

```
11352721345377306.00
11352721346734308.00
11352721346734308.00
11352721346734308.00
```

What went wrong? Is there any problem with parsing? How can i get the original values back.?

**Edit**: Without using Decimal Format:

```
1.1352721345377306E16
1.1352721346734308E16
1.1352721346734308E16
1.1352721346734308E16
```

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` to get the value.                                                       `BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(l4);
     System.out.println(df.format(dec));`

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu Thanks. I need to pass the 'double' value since api source is not editable.:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get original values back. Refer this [Java's Floating-Point (Im)Precision](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javas-floating-point-imprecision/240168744).

Comment: I should need that value. is there any alternative?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar: Use BigDecimal?

Comment: Yes BigDecimal can be used.But api is accepting only double and it's a jar which we don't have source.even if i try `BigDecimal.doubleValue` will return same output.

Comment: The exact value can't be stored in a `double`, so in that case your task is impossible.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar maybe save string values somewhere with corresponding double values

Comment: @v.ladynev finally i need to pass double values. I think it's impossible. Let me try it for couple of days.

Answer (score 4):

`double` only has 15/16 digits of accuracy and when you give it a number it can't represent, it takes the closest representable number.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem ? ".00" ? If you don't need this, why using a Double ?

You can try like this...

```
    String l1="11352721345377306";
    String l2="11352721346734307";
    String l3="11352721346734308";
    String l4="11352721346734309";

    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(l1);
    Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(l2);
    Double d3 = Double.parseDouble(l3);  
    Double d4 = Double.parseDouble(l4);

    System.out.println(d1.longValue());
    System.out.println(d2.longValue());
    System.out.println(d3.longValue());  
    System.out.println(d4.longValue());
```

Edit, with BigDecimal to get the correct values:

```
    String l1="11352721345377306";
    String l2="11352721346734307";
    String l3="11352721346734308";
    String l4="11352721346734309";

    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(l1);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(l2);
    BigDecimal bd3 = new BigDecimal(l3);
    BigDecimal bd4 = new BigDecimal(l4);

    System.out.println(bd1);
    System.out.println(bd2);
    System.out.println(bd3);  
    System.out.println(bd4);
```

Output is:

```
11352721345377306
11352721346734307
11352721346734308
11352721346734309
```

Comment: The problem is the values are different.

Comment: Thanks. I need to pass the value type 'double'

Comment: You can't maintain the precision with long or double with larger value.

Comment: As suggested in previous comment, use BigDecimal ?

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu: A `long` can store these values just fine.

Comment: @Keppil Yeah, I see !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
double d = Math.round(Double.parse(yourString) * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

to get double with rounded decimals.

For printing use:

```
String formatted = String.format("%.2f", yourDouble);
```